# BIND9 DNS server config file ( named.config.options)

Tags: domain-name-system

Why my Bind wouldn start with this conf file?

```
options {
        version "Not available";
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        forwarders {
                212.129.64.220;
                212.129.64.221;
};

acl "mynetwork" {
         127/8;  172.16.0.0/12;  10.0.0.0/8;  192.168.0.0/16; };

view "internal" {
         match-clients { mynetwork; };
         allow-query { mynetwork; };
         allow-recursion { mynetwork; };
         match-recursive-only yes;

};

view "external" {
         match-clients { any; };
         allow-query { any; };
         allow-recursion { none; };
         match-recursive-only no;
};
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: I cleaned up the formatting for this question but there are several major parse errors (mostly missing ending braces), but also there doesn't seem to be any question here. Can you please edit and describe your actual question?

Comment: Now just have a look please, i cant realise wat could be wrong...

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the closing brace `}` in your options section. There is a closing brace that works either for the forwarders sub-section or the options section, but you need two so that both get closed.

Also, consider cleaning up the formatting so that separate directives are on separate lines.